# merge multile html files with ant

Tags: java, ant, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have a number of tests which run in parallel. each test generates an extent Report file which is an html file.

I cannot see how to merge these files at the end of tests?

So i want to do this:

file1.html:

```
<body>
      content-1
</body>
```

file2.html

```
<body>
      content-2
</body>
```

The result should be like this:

merge.html

```
<body>
      content-1
      content-2
</body>
```

Have you a clever method to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="concat" name="My Project">

    <property name="filesToMerge" value="/home/guest/Desktop/" />
    <property name="mergeFile" value="/home/guest/Desktop/merge.html" />

    <target name="concat">
        <concat destfile="${mergeFile}">
            <header filtering="no" trim="no" trimleading="yes">
                &lt;body&gt;
            </header>
            <fileset dir="${filesToMerge}" />
            <filterchain>
                <linecontains negate="true">
                    <contains value="&lt;body&gt;" />
                </linecontains>
                <linecontains negate="true">
                    <contains value="&lt;/body&gt;" />
                </linecontains>
            </filterchain>
            <footer filtering="no" trim="yes" trimleading="yes">
                &lt;/body&gt;
            </footer>
        </concat>
    </target>
</project>
```